# What is the difference between BrowserRouter and createBrowserRouter in react-router v6? Can I use createBrowserRouter without using data APIs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, rtk-query

I have read this in the documentation but I am not sure what the difference between `BrowserRouter` and `createBrowserRouter`.

This is what it says in docs:

**createBrowserRouter:**

> This is the recommended router for all React Router web projects. It uses the DOM History API to update the URL and manage the history stack.

> It also enables the v6.4 data APIs like loaders, actions, fetchers and more.

**BrowserRouter:**

> A `<BrowserRouter>` stores the current location in the browser's address bar using clean URLs and navigates using the browser's built-in history stack.

My second question is:

Can I use `createBrowserRouter` without adding data APIs like loaders, actions etc. The reason is I am not sure how to use data APIs with Redux Toolkit Query and I found limited sources. I could perhaps add loaders later.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v6-data#differences 

This should help as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference really is just about as simple as being able to use the Data APIs, e.g. loaders, actions, and a whole host of data-router-only hooks and utility functions (*currently designated by a "new" icon in the docs*).

> Can I use `createBrowserRouter` without adding data APIs like loaders,
> actions etc.

Yes, absolutely you can. There's nothing forcing you (*at this moment*) to use the new data routers ***and*** the Data APIs.

From what I can tell there's some overlap between what loading data and submitting data via route loaders and actions and what Redux-Toolkit/Query provides, but that about the extent of the similarity, data fetching. So far I don't see the Data APIs as a 1-to-1 replacement for redux data caching.

Loaders and actions seem to be useful if the data being fetch is only relevant to a specific React component, or a subtree of routes, whereas Redux is a global state management library and any action can be dispatched from anywhere and the store can be read from anywhere.

If you've already an app using Redux, RTK, and RTK-Query, then I think the loaders/actions will feel a bit underwhelming and clunky. This is at least *my* opinion/experience of them so far. That said, the Data APIs are relatively new and perhaps just haven't found their niche in the React world just yet. For example, I think it's the case that RRD Data APIs likely work well and shine when applied on Server Side Rendering, i.e. Remix, the maintainers of the `react-router` libraries.

Comment: Still a bit unclear. So you are unable to use e.g. `loader` or `action` if you nest `Route` element within a `BrowserRouter`? As opposed to using `createBrowserRouter`?

Comment: @sherrellbc Affirmative, since `BrowserRouter` isn't a "Data Router", none of the data APIs will be available.

Comment: Adding the link to the react router documentation that supports the answer: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#picking-a-router

Answer (score 1):

One major difference would be in blocking navigation. `BrowserRouter` doesn't support `unstable_useBlocker` (it will prompt `useBlocker must be used within a data router feature` warning). You'd need to use `RouterProvider` instead.